# Keras callbacks Tensorboard multi-output Error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, keras-2

I can't figure out what is causing this error for multi-output Keras Model when using callbacks.TensorBoard.

```
tbCallBack = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = logdir, histogram_freq = 1, write_graph = 1, write_images = 0, write_grads = 1)
###No errror when not using callbacks
regr.fit(  Ax_train, [Ay_train_p, Ay_train_s], validation_data= (Ax_test, [Ay_test_p, Ay_test_s]), epochs = 500, batch_size = 10, verbose = 1)
###No errror when not using validation_data
regr.fit(  Ax_train, [Ay_train_p, Ay_train_s], epochs = 500, batch_size = 10, verbose = 1, callbacks=[tbCallBack])
###Error Occurred
regr.fit( Ax_train, [Ay_train_p, Ay_train_s], validation_data= (Ax_test, [Ay_test_p, Ay_test_s]), epochs = 500, batch_size = 10, verbose = 1, callbacks=[tbCallBack])
```

Error

```
Epoch 1/500
1280/1663 [======================>.......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6230 - output_power_loss: 0.9627 - output_slack_loss: 0.66032017-07-11 03:17:27.964542: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1148] Invalid argument: Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
2017-07-11 03:17:27.964589: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:644] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
     [[Node: output_slack_sample_weights = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
2017-07-11 03:17:27.970690: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1148] Invalid argument: Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
2017-07-11 03:17:27.970735: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:644] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
     [[Node: output_power_sample_weights = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
2017-07-11 03:17:27.972004: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1148] Invalid argument: Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
2017-07-11 03:17:27.972026: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:644] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
     [[Node: output_power_sample_weights = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf_keras.py", line 183, in <module>
    regr.fit( Ax_train, [Ay_train_p, Ay_train_s], validation_data= (Ax_test, [Ay_test_p, Ay_test_s]), epochs = 500, batch_size = 10, verbose = 1, callbacks=[tbCallBack])
  File "/home/roy/keras_tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1507, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/roy/keras_tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1176, in _fit_loop
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "/home/roy/keras_tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 77, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "/home/roy/keras_tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 768, in on_epoch_end
    result = self.sess.run([self.merged], feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/home/roy/keras_tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 789, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/roy/keras_tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 997, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/roy/keras_tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1132, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/roy/keras_tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1152, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
     [[Node: output_power_sample_weights = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'output_power_sample_weights', defined at:
  File "tf_keras.py", line 180, in <module>
    regr = nn_model()
  File "tf_keras.py", line 177, in nn_model
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss ={'output_power': 'mean_squared_error', 'output_slack': 'binary_crossentropy'})
  File "/home/roy/keras_tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 870, in compile
    name=name + '_sample_weights'))
  File "/home/roy/keras_tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 431, in placeholder
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/home/roy/keras_tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1530, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops._placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/home/roy/keras_tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1954, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/home/roy/keras_tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/roy/keras_tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/roy/keras_tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
     [[Node: output_power_sample_weights = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

What does "Shape [-1] has negative dimensions" means? I had also tried with each output with callbacks.Tensorboard and there wasn't any error occurred. Also search with "Node: output_power_sample_weights" but no results.

regr.summary()

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
main_input (InputLayer)          (None, 5)             0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Hidden (Dense)                   (None, 5)             30          main_input[0][0]                 
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
output_power (Dense)             (None, 1)             6           Hidden[0][0]                     
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
output_slack (Dense)             (None, 1)             6           Hidden[0][0]                     
====================================================================================================
Total params: 42
Trainable params: 42
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: could you print `model.summary()`?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I had edited the post on your comment. Is it related to the output layer where both connected to hidden[0][0] (wild guess)? Kindly guide me through this, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Shape [-1] has negative dimensions" error message is a (misleading) error printed when you don't feed a [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) that has a partially-defined shape. This error message has been replaced with a more informative message in the nightly version of TensorFlow.

The error and the stack trace suggests that this `Session.run()` call is failing ([source](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/99ba51555f1bac68742ee2b85f3d452c0531e343/keras/callbacks.py#L767)):

```
  File "/home/roy/keras_tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 768, in on_epoch_end
    result = self.sess.run([self.merged], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Looking at [the implementation](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/99ba51555f1bac68742ee2b85f3d452c0531e343/keras/callbacks.py#L767), it appears that this is only called when the [`TensorBoard`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/99ba51555f1bac68742ee2b85f3d452c0531e343/keras/callbacks.py#L581) callback is installed, and [`self.validation_data` is not `None`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/99ba51555f1bac68742ee2b85f3d452c0531e343/keras/callbacks.py#L744). From the implementation, it looks like this callback is incompatible with models that depend on placeholders that are not [one of](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/99ba51555f1bac68742ee2b85f3d452c0531e343/keras/callbacks.py#L748) (i) `model.inputs`, (ii) `model.targets`, or (iii) `model.sample_weights`. It might be best to open an issue on the [Keras GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues) about this.

Comment: This is correct. The issue arrisses at `keras.callbacks.py:768` but its origination is at this line `batch_val.append(val_data[3])` in `keras.callbacks.TensorBoard.on_epoch_end()`. This results in an unbalanced zipping below at `zip(tensors, batch_val)` when there is multiple inputs or outputs.